# itextsharp sign LTV Pades

Tags: c#, itext

I am currently programming a digital signer in C # with iTextSharp library. Initially the signer works properly, as he signed the document, requested the pin, etc. Everything was fine until asked me to sign and also activate LTV, which in this case uses PAdES.

The document to be signed is a PDF, which must bear a mark of a TSA, in an instance what I do is

```
ITSAClient t = new TSAClientBouncyCastle ( "myURL");
```

So far things went well.
But when I try to add the LTV as follows

```
MakeSignature.SignDetached (signatureAppearance, externalSignature, chain, null, null, t, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);
LtvVerification v = pdfStamper.LtvVerification;

LtvTimestamp.Timestamp (signatureAppearance, t, null);
```

And send me a message saying

> "Already pre Document closed"

Could some please help me?

Comment: `MakeSignature.SignDetached` already closes the document. If you want to add some changes thereafter, you have to read the generated pdf again with a new `PdfReader` and manipulate it with a new `PdfStamper`.

Comment: thanks, this means that i need put, LtvTimestamp.Timestamp (signatureAppearance, t, null);, before SignDetached ?????

Comment: No, `LtvTimestamp.Timestamp` also closes the document. Time stamping technically is very much akin to signing.